# change div content using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace a the following div with a similar div in a file called file.php when clicked. the div tag is..

```html
<div  style="display: none;" id="extra" class="container2" xml:id="page">
  <div class="title">
   <h2>Stuff to check out</h2>
   <span class="byline">gotta gets that money</span> </div>
  <div id="three-column">
   <div class="boxA">
    <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span>
     <p>Praesent pellentesque facilisis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxB">
    <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
     <p>Etiam neque. Vivamus consequat lorem at nisl. Nullam non wisi a sem semper eleifend. Donec mattis.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxC">
    <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
     <p> Aenean lectus lorem, imperdiet at, ultrices eget, ornare et, wisi. Pellentesque adipiscing purus.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="actions">
   <li><a id="addContent" href="#" class="button">Close</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the JavaScript function is..

```js
$('#addContent').click(function(){
   $("#extra").load("file.php");
   return false;
});
```

the file.php looks exactly like the above div. can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong. ps, i want to replace the div with multiple file.php files when clicked with a seamless transition. thanks.

Comment: Hi, have you considered using jQuery ?

Comment: @KristianHareland, it looks like he *is* using jQuery because of the JS snippet.

Comment: @KristianHareland OP tagged `jQuery` and also already used jQuery.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali, my bad. On mobile device so didnt see tags at once.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not replace the `div#addContent`, but it will put the similar `div` *inside* `div#addContent`. To replace it with the similar `div`, put it inside a container and then load your similar `div` from the PHP file into the container.

## SAMPLE

```
<div id="container">
  <div  style="display: none;" id="extra" class="container2" xml:id="page">
          <div class="title">
              <h2>Stuff to check out</h2>
              <span class="byline">gotta gets that money</span> </div>
          <div id="three-column">
              <div class="boxA">
                  <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span>
                      <p>Praesent pellentesque facilisis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="boxB">
                  <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
                      <p>Etiam neque. Vivamus consequat lorem at nisl. Nullam non wisi a sem semper eleifend. Donec mattis.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="boxC">
                  <div class="box"> <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                      <p> Aenean lectus lorem, imperdiet at, ultrices eget, ornare et, wisi. Pellentesque adipiscing purus.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="actions">
              <li><a id="addContent" href="#" class="button">Close</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then,

```
$('#addContent').click(function(){
   $("#container").load("file.php");
   return false;
});
```

I hope that was helpful!

Comment: when clicked on..nothing.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your PHP file, because it works perfectly according to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfmLyvgh/). In the fiddle, I removed the `display: none;` from your `div` element as well, which is why it wasn't displaying in the browser.

Comment: the jsfiidle snippet gives me an error as well, Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return ....